# another non-scripted solution for elastic multicolumn layout with background color extending full scroll height

Tags: css, multiple-columns

This is an infamous css problem, and there are lots of partial solutions out there that didn't suit my needs.

I was previously using a Javascript solution, but encountered problems when my browser was caching iframes and then preloading them when I use the backarrow *before* running the css-fixing js, even though I was setting the src attribute of the iframes *after* the css-fixing code completed.  This lead to a screwed up appearance while the iframes loaded.  Perhaps there is a fix for this, but a css-only solution is nice if it does what you need.

So the question is: how can I have two or more columns of content, *each* with elastic (percentage) width and length with background colors that extend to the bottom of the *scroll* height (including to the bottom of the page if there is little or no content and hence no scrolling) without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in Firefox and Chrome.  jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JBBT/4/

I suppose this solution of mine is partial if you consider the fact that, if instead of a solid background color, you wanted to use a background image, this would only work if you were willing to have the image remain fixed while the content scrolls over it (which you may not want).

Anyway, someone may have come up with this solution before, but I haven't seen it or didn't implement it correctly if I saw it and tried it.  I'm no css expert so please share any improvements.

Given n columns, and the width (in percentage if you want) you want each to occupy, first create an empty div for each that will serve as their respective backgrounds (colors).  Order shouldn't matter.

```
    <div id="leftbg"></div>
    <div id="rightbg"></div>
    <div id="middlebg"></div>
```

and

```
#leftbg
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#rightbg{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 24%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}
#middlebg{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width:62%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 24%;
    left: 14%; 
}
```

Note for example, that the     `left` style attribute of     `#middlebg` is the same as the `width` attribute of `#leftbg`, and so on.

Then I float content containers with each column's content above each of those backgrounds.  For this example, I only put content in the left and middle columns.

```
<div id="leftcontainer">
    <div id="leftcontent"><p>hello</p></div>
</div>

<div id="middlecontainer">
    <div id="middlecontent"><p>hello</p></div>
</div>
```

Though of course, the whole point of this solution is that you can have more than just `<p>hello</p>` as your content.  If your content goes beyond the page, it can scroll, and the background colors stay behind it.

css for the containers:

```
#leftcontainer{
    width: 14%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#middlecontainer{
    width: 62%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Note the widths are the same as their respective background divs.  The containers and content have no background. It's just text/whatever that is made to float over the background divs.

At this point, as long as you don't make the content divs fixed or absolute positioned, I believe you can effectively treat each column as a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox (Flexible Box Layout Module). See http://jsbin.com/bedap/1/.

More on Flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Chris Coyier also has a nice collection of info here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Note that browser support, while good, is not complete and may require fallbacks, and that many people (myself included) do not recommend Flexbox for page layout, as nested flexboxes can get unruly.